# How to Control Highchart.js Dom Elements Through CSS Rules

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/o7jrucf6/) and let me know How I can control CSS rules of Highchart element like Title or Back color?
I know that Highchart is providing this with some internal properties and functions but I need to do this through CSS and Dom Manipulation , as well.

Here is a code That I tried to change the color of the Highchart Title:

```
.highcharts-title{color:red !important;}
```

but it didn't work!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is the preferred way to do it.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/o7jrucf6/2/

```
    $('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    title: {
         style: {
            color: 'red'          
         }            
      },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]



});
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ali Thanks for reply but as I said I need to do this with CSS. let me explain more, I need to hide the title on small media querirs, so I tought we may be able to work with dom element on highchart to do this

Comment: I am not sure if they allow you to do that via CSS. I see the source and there is a inline styling being applied hence your CSS isn't coming into affect. Took a look into their docs too

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts uses SVG for drawing, so you'll need to use the [proper SVG attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#SVGStylingProperties).  In your example above it's fill not color:

```
.highcharts-title{fill:red !important;}
```

Updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/o7jrucf6/8/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `useHTML` flag in title, as true.

```
title:{ 
   text: 'any',
   useHTML: true
}
```